# SQL grouping unique occurrences by date

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, distinct, conditional-aggregation

I am looking for a MySQL query to count how many people visited a web-app. I have a database storing information about visitors, they type and when they tried to login:

```
+-----+-----------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id  | person_id | area   | success | date_created        |
+-----+-----------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| 762 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-06-28 09:22:35 |
| 763 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-06-28 11:22:35 |
| 764 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-06-28 14:22:35 |
| 765 |       102 | client |       1 | 2022-06-28 15:04:43 |
| 766 |       101 |   user |       1 | 2022-06-28 16:04:43 |
| 767 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-06-29 15:07:29 |
| 768 |       101 |   user |       1 | 2022-06-30 09:18:41 |
| 769 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-07-01 09:24:46 |
| 770 |       101 |   user |       1 | 2022-07-01 09:25:59 |
| 771 |       102 | client |       1 | 2022-07-01 14:17:57 |
| 772 |       103 | client |       1 | 2022-07-01 15:20:14 |
| 773 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-07-02 13:01:49 |
| 774 |       100 | client |       1 | 2022-07-03 09:06:00 |
| 775 |       102 | client |       0 | 2022-07-03 12:11:23 |
| 776 |       103 | client |       1 | 2022-07-03 12:41:43 |
```

I need to parse a `date_created` to `date`, sum unique occurrences of `person_id` if the `are` is `client` and sum by date.

Wouldn't have a problem to do it in other programming language but I struggle with building the query in SQL. Need to do it on the box and can't really get much installed there.

The expected result:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| date       | successful_clients |
+------------+--------------------+
| 2022-06-28 |                  2 |
| 2022-06-29 |                  1 |
| 2022-06-30 |                  0 |
| 2022-07-01 |                  3 |
| 2022-07-02 |                  1 |
| 2022-07-03 |                  2 |
```

What would be efficient SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(date_created) date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN success AND area = 'client' THEN person_id END) successful_clients 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/__U0_DSa).